# Section number with mixed arabic and roman numerals

Tags: sectioning, numbering

How can I get my `sections` and `subsections` headings to go along the lines of: `1i, 1ii, 1iii, 2i, 2ii` etc...

Comment: This can be done using `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}\roman{subsection}}` but the output isn't very nice.

Comment: How should subsubsections be numbered?

Comment: Could you give some feedback about the solution?

Answer (score 4):

All LaTeX counters automatically define a counter format routine, named `\the...`, e.g. if the counter is named `foo`, than there is `\thefoo`. This defaults to `\arabic{foo}`, i.e. arabic numbers, unless a driver counter was given too.

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}\roman{subsection}}
```

will use the arabic format of `section` and the roman format output of `subsection. It will output the subsections as requested, but it **does not** look very nice.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}\roman{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```