# How to make roman numeral sub sections?

Tags: roman-numerals

my sub section headers are III.3    how to i make the three roman numerals

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
```

I have this in preamble

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE! Try `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}} ` .

Comment: Maybe `\roman{subsection}`, don't you think?

Comment: [Roman numerals for sections and subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26882/134144) might be related. Depending on the desired output [Section number with mixed arabic and roman numerals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239611/134144)  could ylso be interesting.